# Multi-dimensional right-corners intersecting a plane

Tags: geometry, spacetime-dimensions

In 3d space, a right-corner can intersect a 2d plane, like lopping off the corner of a cube to create a tetrahedron.  Can higher dimensional 'right-corners' in $N$ dimensions, where all dimensions are 90 degrees perpendicular to each other, be rotated through space to also intersect a 2d plane?  Or can they only intersect the $N-1$ space?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a 2D plane could "cut off" a corner of an N - dimensional hypercube, then the intersection would make up a face of the corner, i.e. parts of its surface. But a surface has dimensions N-1, while the intersection of a plane with the hypercube can have dimensions at most 2

Comment: Thanks, user33..  I was doing a 'thought experiment' and was trying to see what the fewest dimensions I could reduce any N-d shape to.  Your summary got me back on track.

Answer (score 0):

This is a math question, but consider a square. Consider a line in the (1,1) direction, which points to the opposite corner of the square. A line perpendicular to this line cuts the corner of the square, leaving a right triangle.

Consider a cube. Consider a line in the (1,1, 1) direction, which points to the opposite corner of the cube. A plane perpendicular to this line cuts the corner of the cube, leaving a right tetrahedron.

Consider a hypercube... Can you keep going?